# Tracking memory usage allocated within C++ wrapped by Cython

Tags: python, c++, memory, cython

I have a Python program which calls some Cython code which in turn wraps some raw C++ code. I would like to see how much memory the base C++ code is allocating. I've tried the memory_profiler module for Python, however, it can't seem to detect anything allocated by the C++ code. My evidence for this is that I have a Cython object that in turn stores an instance of a C++ object. This C++ object should definitely hold onto a bunch of memory. In python, when I create an instance of the Cython object (and it stores an instance of the C++ object), memory_profiler does not detect any extra memory stored (or at least detects only a negligible amount).

Is there any other way to detect how much memory Python is having allocated by the base C++ objects? Or is there something similar to memory_profiler, but for Cython?

Answer (score 1):

If you can run your program on Linux, use https://github.com/vmware/chap (for example, start with "summarize used").